Nginx catch-all routes, except root route
So, I have a URL Shortener website, and I want ONLY the root path to be served via static files and other routes to be redirected to their destination via API.
I found the solution with location = /, but it didn't help much.
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name domain.com;

    ...

    # Home page
    location = / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html;
    }

    # Redirects
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://api:3000/v1/urls/redirect$uri;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}


Your webpage index.html probably contains URLs for resource files (e.g. CSS, JS, images). If these are served by this server, they also require exceptions.

Directive index would causes an internal redirect, and the request can be processed in a different location, a / request will actually be processed in the second location as /index.html.
You can config as:
server {
    
  ...
  
  location = / {
    index /c0g2af/index.html;
  }

  location / {
        proxy_pass   http://api:3000/v1/urls/redirect$uri;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /c0g2af/ {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
    
}

Create a directory in /usr/share/nginx/html and name it as random code, for example c0g2af.

It did work!!! Thank you, but the problem is that static files do not apply as they are redirected (as @richard-smith mentioned). Is there any way to keep static files in the root path? domain.com/terms.pdf or must I keep them in domain.com/static/ route so we can locate them using nginx?

I put this for now, thanks
location ~* \.(css|js|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|pdf)$ {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/domain-com;
    try_files $uri =404;
}


usually, the request to server would add /api to the beginning of uri
